# Can't create temporary file in PHP despite the temp directory exists

Tags: php

i'm making a site that allow the user to upload images. 
When I make the call to the $_FILE variable in order to move the image to another directory it does nothing. Checking the $_FILE with print_r shows the next information:

```
(
    [pic1] => Array
        (
            [name] => pic1
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 6
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

The error 6 seems to be [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

```
UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR

Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 5.0.3.
```

But I have a big problem: I can access only to the directory where I put the files, I can't check if the temp directory exists or check the php.ini (The server is from my client, and he can't give me access to other directories)

Fortunately the client is checking these parameters and telling me how they are.
So, the temporary directory (upload_tmp_dir) is set to /tmp
The /tmp directory actually exists, and have all the permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwt 34 root root 2832 2014-08-30 00:00 tmp
```

I've been searching reasons of why it shows the error of "Missing temporary folder" despite it exists, but i can't find a reason or a solution. I leave [here a pastebin with the output of ini_get_all()](http://pastebin.com/KkMLGuVw)

If you can comment any possible solution i'll be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to change which directory is "tmp" using this function: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir

but apparently, you'll have to have this done in the core ini file: http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/1c87xk/can_i_use_ini_set_to_set_the_value_of_upload_tmp/

Comment: I guess that changing the tmp folder could be a solution. It seems that upload_tmp_dir has the PHP_INI_SYSTEM by default. Do you know if it can be changed to PHP_INI_ALL in some way? Doing this i could use ini_set to change it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Get your client to fix their server's configuration.

There's nothing you can do if they have things broken, and I can't imagine they would fight you on having to fix it.  This is not a technical problem... you've already solved the technical part.

Comment: Yeah, in fact the server has other issues and the client is fixing them, but with this particular problem has requested me for help.

Comment: Add you should, and to help them fix their config and/or permissions

Answer (score 0):

Check for `open_basedir`. If it is on, the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) states:

> If open_basedir is on, then the system default directory must be
>   allowed for an upload to succeed.

Also you could specify a custom directory, and you should check that it isn't already set but not writable. Also stated on that same page is that if the directory specified is not writable, PHP falls back to the system default temporary directory (/tmp).

Comment: It seems that open_basedir is set to Off. I'll try changing the custom directory to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure how nobody pointed it out. But as far as I know. Nobody runs php under root permissions which the folder /tmp has the root:root ownership. I can only assume that if you will use `file_put_contents` or `fopen('/tmp/some_new_file')...` it should result with some permission denied or like. Therefore you should update the php.INI permanently with an accessible folder for the php user to avoid reoccurrence of the error